# JDBC + mysql remoto erro ao conectar

Tags: java, jdbc

## Introdução

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em java que possa alterar a conexão do banco de dados, tenho 1 banco local (127.0.0.1:3306) e um banco remoto (192.168.25.75:3306) que seria um computador meu, fiz a conexão utilizando o jdbc.

#### connDb.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author ralfting
 */
public class ConnDb {
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        String conexao = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.75:3306/teste";
        String usuario = "root";
        String senha = "root";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";


            Class.forName(driver);
            java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, usuario, senha);
            System.out.println("Conexão - OK");
            return (Connection) conn;


    }
}
```

#### JDBC Driver

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Problema

Quando utilizo o banco local funciona perfeitamente, mas a partir que começo a utilizar o banco remoto ele não funciona ele me retorna um `SQLException`

> null,  message from server: "Host 'Ralfting.home' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: A mensagem de erro é bastante clara. Você não tem permissão para conectar com esse banco. Verifique se a porta está aberta (firewall pode interferir nisso) e que consegue conectar da sua máquina nesse banco.

Comment: Alguns bancos remotos, principalmente os de hosts gratuitos só permitem conexões a partir de páginas hospedadas no próprio servidor. Uma possível solução para o seu caso é fazer um acesso REST para se comunicar com sua aplicação local.

Comment: Desculpa, lendo melhor sua pergunta percebi que o banco remoto está em outro computador seu, correto? Nesse caso o comentário do Kyllopardiun é mais útil, pois pode ser algum firewall ou coisa do tipo. De qualquer forma, não temos como descobrir a causa do erro se você não der mais detalhes do seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solução

Era esse mesmo o problema @Kyllopardiun falou,abrindo as portas e resolvido isso tive um problema nesse mesmo código na hora de inserir, ele fechava conexão antes de inserir:

```
try{
    Class.forName(driver);
    java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, usuario, senha);
    System.out.println("Conexão - OK");
    return (Connection) conn;

}catch(SQLException e){}
```

#### Erro

> Closed Connection

Assim fazendo com que libera os recursos alocados quando da criação de "conn"; ou seja, fecha a conexão com o banco. Removendo o `try catch` funciono corretamente.

```
Class.forName(driver);
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, usuario, senha);
System.out.println("Conexão - OK");
return (Connection) conn;
```

Comment: +1 pela solução, mas principalmente por ter voltado depois de 2 dias pra responder.  :D